# Filter fields from 1/n table using clause on multiple columns

Tags: php, mysql

ok, first of all sorry for the title, but I could not work out a better one :(
This is the problem:
I have two tables, `properties` and `properties_rooms`, linked each other by the propery ID.

```
properties table:

+---------------+------------+
| id_properties | pr_title   |
+---------------+------------+
|             1 | test       |
|             2 | dummy      |
+---------------+------------+

properties_rooms table:
+---------------+-------------------+--------------+----------+
| id_prop_rooms | pro_id_properties | pro_id_rooms | pro_size |
+---------------+-------------------+--------------+----------+
|             1 |                 1 |            4 |     5.00 |
|             2 |                 1 |           18 |    17.00 |
|             3 |                 2 |            6 |    12.00 |
|             4 |                 2 |           24 |    11.00 |
|             5 |                 1 |            4 |    10.00 |
|             6 |                 1 |            6 |    10.00 |
|             7 |                 1 |            6 |    12.00 |
+---------------+-------------------+--------------+----------+
```

I'm working on an advanced search, where users can search for a property that has more than a rooms of the same type (ie two bedrooms, 3 bathrooms and so on).

Sadly, I find myself stuck on this, since I can't "filter" the same dataset with multiple clause; if i have to filter only one there will be no problems, since I can use an `HAVING` clause.

I worked out this select:

```
SELECT id_properties, pro_id_rooms, COUNT(*) as total, 
        IF ((pro_id_rooms = 4 AND COUNT(*) >= 2) OR (pro_id_rooms = 6 AND COUNT(*) >= 2), 1, 0) as flag
FROM `properties`
INNER JOIN properties_rooms ON id_properties = pro_id_properties
WHERE id_properties IN (4,10)
GROUP BY id_properties, pro_id_rooms
ORDER BY id_properties
```

Inside the `IN` clause there are the properties that I know they have at least one of requested rooms. They came from a previous query since I have to work with `GROUP BY` and `HAVING`.
The `IF` part inside the select is built at run-time, since I get the information from the request.
This is the result:

```
+---------------+--------------+-------+------+
| id_properties | pro_id_rooms | total | flag |
+---------------+--------------+-------+------+
|             1 |            4 |     2 | 1    |
|             1 |            6 |     2 | 1    |
|             1 |           18 |     1 | 0    |
|             2 |            6 |     1 | 0    |
|             2 |           24 |     1 | 0    |
+---------------+--------------+-------+------+
```

I think it could work, I only need to add an `HAVING flag > 0` and I'm done.

My question is, is there anything better?
Tables aren't very large: properties one could be something like 1k, rooms one about 10k.
I'm afraid that if the user puts too much rooms, the query would become an enormous `IF` statement...

Comment: It's not exactly clear to me what you want to accomplish... Do you have a search form with checkboxes for instance 'number of rooms' or 'room size' where users can input multiple selections?

Comment: almost... there is a search form where users can add the room type and (optionally) the number of rooms; but there is no search for room size.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT id_properties, SUM(pro_id_rooms = 4) AS bedrooms, SUM(pro_id_rooms = 6) AS bathrooms
FROM `properties`
INNER JOIN properties_rooms ON id_properties = pro_id_properties
WHERE id_properties IN (4,10)
GROUP BY id_properties
HAVING bedrooms >= 3 AND bathrooms >= 2
```

### Changes

```
SUM(pro_id_rooms = 4) AS bedrooms, SUM(pro_id_rooms = 6) AS bathrooms
```

For each checkbox the user has selected, you need a `SUM(pro_id_rooms = x) AS nrofx` in your `WHERE`.

```
HAVING bedrooms >= 3 AND bathrooms >= 2
```

This is where you check the number of a particular room.

Comment: mhm sorry but that won't work. for example user can search for 2 bedrooms and 3 bathrooms, so how can handle that?

Comment: @tampe125 okay, found something you could use, updated answer.

Comment: nice, that should do the work! Btw I have to remove `pro_id_rooms` from the group by clause but it should work. I'll test it asap